# Javascript syntax issue in code

Tags: javascript

Can someone tell me why this bit of JavaScript is buggy?
I have HTML also, but I don't want to make this a massive code dump.

```
<script type = 'text/javascript'>
var playerCards = [];
var dealerCards = [];

function deal() {
    var newCard = Math.random() % 12;
    var newCard2 = Math.random() % 12;
    playerCards += newCard;
    playerCards += newCard2;

    var counter = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < playerCards.length; ++i) {

        counter += i;
    }
    document.getElementById("playerTotal").innerHTML = counter;

    var dCounter = 0;
    for (var j = 0; j < playerCards.length; ++j) {

        dCounter += j;
    }
    document.getElementById("dealerTotal").innerHTML = dCounter;

}
</script>
```

I'm gonna assume this is a silly syntax error someplace, but I can't find it.

Comment: What is the problem you are seeing?

Comment: what is the problem ?

Comment: I don't believe += adds elements to an array unless that's a feature I'm unaware of. Try playerCards.push(newCard). Could be other things though as you haven't explained what's wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Math.random returns a number between 0 and 1 - so Math.random() % 12 will probably be zero

```
var playerCards = [];
playerCards += newCard; //
```

what are you even trying to do there?

```
var counter = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < playerCards.length; ++i) {

    counter += i;
}
```

if playerCards had a length, this loop would result in counter having value of 0, 1, 3, 6, 10 .. n(n+1) / 2 - probably not what you intended, but who knows

Answer (score 3):

I'm guessing that this isn't doing what you expect it to:

```
playerCards += newCard;
playerCards += newCard2;
```

Try this instead:

```
playerCards.push(newCard);
playerCards.push(newCard2);
```

The first snippet is trying to "add" a number to an array, which doesn't exactly make sense. Through some arcane JavaScript rules, this turns the result into a string.

I'm guessing that you want to concatenate to an array instead.